# MySQL stop/waiting issues; “can't connect … through socket”

Tags: mysql, services, apache-httpd, bodhi

So this was my first time putting up a LAMP stack on a Bodhi machine (previously experience with WAMP, and LAMP on 10.04); I got Apache going, and a Drupal install begun, then I go to create a new database and when I log in to phpmyadmin ... I get a 'cannot connect error'. Tracing this back, the issue began once I tried to get virtual hosts up and running in Apache; once that was done I started running into socket connection issues with mysql.

Initially the problem looked like this:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Using `ls -lart /var/run/my*` I get this:

```
  total 0
  drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql root  40 Jan 31 11:56 .
  drwxr-xr-x 21 root  root 740 Jan 31 12:21 ..`
```

I ran `touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` and set `chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld` which allows for:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 21 root  root 740 Jan 31 12:21 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql root   0 Jan 31 13:58 mysqld.sock
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql root  60 Jan 31 13:58 .
```

- So when I try to run `mysql -u root -p` I get one error - `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)` (note it is no longer ERROR 2002...(2) but rather ERROR 2002...(13))
- If I try `service mysql restart` (or stop, start) I get another error - `start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.49" (uid=1000 pid=8407 comm="start mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")`
- When I run `sudo service mysql restart` I get `stop: Unknown instance: 
  start: Job failed to start`
- When I run `service mysql status` I get "mysql stop/waiting"

What can I do to diagnose the issues I am having with mysql? I may be overlooking an utterly simple mysql issue and would appreciate any feedback on what I've done so far.

Also, being a Bodhi machine and most of the instruction/feedback being written for Ubuntu, I am unsure to what extent any Ubuntu instruction may not apply. In particular, am I running into a problem related to the difference between `/etc/init.d/...` and `service ... ...` commands? Or, perhaps, am I running into a difference between libraries of the two?

Comment: Please post the content of the MySQL error log.

Answer (score 2):

check in your `nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf` open the file .
Search for `bind-address` in file if it is `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` than you should be able to login but if it is something other than `localhost` than you have to give host to your mysql command `mysql -uroot -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p`